# Error 404 when Pairing Workflow Server with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, powershell, error, 404

when I try this in powershell:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService –SPSite "http://spserver2013" –WorkflowHostUri http://spserver2013:12291" –AllowOAuthHttp
```

I get this error:

```
    Register-SPWorkflowService : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://spserver2013" -WorkflowHostUri "http: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:
   RegisterSPWorkflowService) [Register-SPWorkflowService], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell
   .RegisterSPWorkflowService
```

here is what I got from Logs:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSecurityTokenServiceJsonMetadataClient.DownloadMetadata(Uri metadataEndpointUri)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedProviderBase.UpdateFromMetadataFeed(Boolean isFirstTime)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedProviderBase..ctor(SPPersistedObject parent, String name, String description, X509Certificate2 certificate, Uri metadataEndPoint, SPSecurityTokenServiceJsonMetadataDocument metadataDocument)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedProviderBase..ctor(SPPersistedObject parent, String name, String description, Uri metadataEndPoint)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedSecurityTokenService..ctor(SPPersistedObject parent, String name, String description, Uri metadataEndPoint)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceHelper.EnsureTrustedSecurityTokenService(Uri metadataEndpoint, Boolean allowHttp)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.ConfigureOAuth(Boolean allowOAuthHttp)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

[image]

get-wffarm:

```
    FarmType                   : Workflow
WFFarmDBConnectionString   : Data Source=sqlserver2012;Initial
                             Catalog=WFManagementDB;Integrated
                             Security=True;Encrypt=False
RunAsAccount               : sp_workflow@XXXXXX
AdminGroup                 : BUILTIN\Administrators
Hosts                      : {Name: spserver2013.XXXXXXX.com, Configuration
                             State: HostConfigurationCompleted}
InstanceDBConnectionString : Data Source=sqlserver2012;Initial
                             Catalog=WFInstanceManagementDB;Integrated
                             Security=True;Asynchronous
                             Processing=True;Encrypt=False
ResourceDBConnectionString : Data Source=sqlserver2012;Initial
                             Catalog=WFResourceManagementDB;Integrated
                             Security=True;Asynchronous
                             Processing=True;Encrypt=False
HttpPort                   : 12291
HttpsPort                  : 12290
OutboundCertificate        : Thumbprint:
                             EF7820779415339B6EAE127A756677E265E6C7FB,
                             IsGenerated: True
Endpoints                  : {https://spserver2013.XXXXXX.com:12290/}
SslCertificate             : Thumbprint:
                             0DAF61EB086953AB8D07BFDB09F68724BDFF12FC,
                             IsGenerated: True
EncryptionCertificate      : Thumbprint:
                             0DAF61EB086953AB8D07BFDB09F68724BDFF12FC,
                             IsGenerated: True
```

I have sharepoint 2013 sp1 on windows server 2012 r2 updated

I've Uninstalled and Installed workflow manager several times, but the same result occurs.

what gives folks?

Comment: The solution is here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98229/installing-workflow-manager-1-0-in-a-sharepoint-2013-sp1-windows-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the CU2 update for workflow manager. It will fix the issue.
http://min2dmax.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/register-spworkflowservice-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found/

Comment: Yes , this helped me to get rid of this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SharePoint 2013 Sp1. Used the following command with a -Force parameter:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://yoursite/" -WorkflowHostUri "http://yoursitecollection:port" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
```